# Toggling button state and reusing toggle function for other buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have four button components that I would like to toggle a primary prop component for, and the primary prop is just a true/false input. When true it changes the button color to purple, when false it is grey. Currently, the only way I would know how to do this is to create a new `toggleProfitView` function that explicitly states `setState({revenueb: !this.state.revenueb})`, and another that does `setState({profitb: !this.state.profitb})` for example, but I have four different button states and I'd like to be able to just reuse a function that knows which button to toggle. I'm trying to be DRY with my code. In pseudocode it would be something like,

```
this.button.primary.state = !this.button.primary.state
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
toggleProfitView(key, event) {
    console.log(event)
    var plot_number = this.state.plot_number
     this.setState({variant_plot_data: this.props.final_plot[plot_number]}, () => {
      this.updatePlots(key);
    });
  }

function PlotIfDataExists(props) {
  const dataExists = props.dataExists;
  if(dataExists) {
    return (<div>
              <ProductGraphData variant_plot_data = {variant_plot_data} />
              <Stack spacing="none" distribution="leading">
                <Select
                  options={props.variants}
                  placeholder="Select"
                  onChange={props.handleVariantChange}
                />
                <Button onClick={props.toggleVariantPlotData}>Next Plot</Button>
                <Button primary={props.revenueb} onClick={(event) => props.toggleView('revenue', event)}>Revenue Plot</Button>
                <Button primary={props.profitb} onClick={(event) => props.toggleView('profit', event)}>Profit Plot</Button>
                <Button primary={props.profitvb} onClick={(event) => props.toggleView('profit_per_view', event)}>Profit/View Plot</Button>
                <Button primary={props.revenuevb} onClick={(event) => props.toggleView('rev_per_view', event)}>Rev/View Plot</Button>
                <Button onClick={props.showAllPlots}>Show All</Button>
              </Stack>
              <LastPriceTestContainer analytics_data = {variant_plot_data} />
            </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, how about a custom Button component that manages it's own color state onClick. You could still call an onClick passed in by the parent if the parent needs to know anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using a hash to maintain the states.

```
 toggleView(key, event) {
    const button_states_hash = Object.assign({}, this.state.button_states);
    button_states_hash[key] = !button_states_hash[key]
    var plot_number = this.state.plot_number
     this.setState({
       variant_plot_data: this.props.final_plot[plot_number],
       button_states: button_states_hash
     }, () => {
      this.updatePlots(key);
    });
  }
```